# Basic spring mvc app in intellij is giving 404 not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

My basic spring mvc web application is giving this error.
[image]

I am using intellij idea community edition. Here is the snapshot of project structure

[image]

Content of pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <name>SpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>SpringMVC</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Content of web.xml is

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<!--  Configure Dispatcher Servlet-->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Content of index.jsp is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello World!</h2>
        <h1> This is called by controller </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Content of homeController.java is

```
package springmvc.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("This is home url");
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Content of spring-servlet.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="springmvc.controller"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" name="viewResolver">
        <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I am not able to find the mistake I am doing. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the configuration? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely items missing from you project that explain the 404. These are what I have noticed:

In pom.xml the dependency: `org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.2.4.RELEASE` should be replaced with: `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.4.0`. spring-boot-starters ensure that all the necessary is done.

You need a class that extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` and is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTomcatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

When the WAR file is dropped into webapps the following should appear in the logs:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.73\webapps\SpringMVC.war]
```

and then the usual Spring Boot banner should appear, ending with:

```
Started SpringBootTomcatApplication in 5.755 seconds (JVM running for 183.04)
Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'spring'
Initializing Servlet 'spring'
Completed initialization in 323 ms
Deployment of web application archive [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.73\webapps\SpringMVC.war] has finished in [13,698] ms
```

I found this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp) to be helpful.

This is the complete project pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <name>SpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>SpringMVC</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

package springmvc;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTomcatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {}
```

Further than that I used your code.

Comment: http://localhost:9494/SpringMVC/home is giving same error as http://localhost:9494/SpringMVC/

Comment: Are you running it with **mvn spring-boot:run** or are you dropping the warfile in a tomcat webapps? Do you have a class with a '@SpringBootApplication' annotation? If so please add it to the answer.

Comment: No, I am not running it with mvn spring-boot:run. I am dropping war in tomcat webapps.

Comment: When you drop the warfile or when it starts while webapps already contains the warfile does it 1) create a folder in webapps called StringMVC that contains the unzipped contents of the warfile and 2) if so do the logs include words to the effect of "INFO: Deploying web application directory [C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.73\webapps\SpringMVC]"? Maybe add the Tomcat startup logs to the question.

Comment: I have make significant updates to my answer.